# How to resize images inside a flexbox without using a background image?

Tags: css, flexbox

I know there are a LOT of examples of this, and I have tried all of them to no avail. I am trying to create a carousel component that resizes images according to its boundary. I am using it in a myriad of places, in a myriad of different ways, so it MUST be responsive. I also need the images to be clickable as normal images for `a11y` and customers (managing expectations).

Here is my fiddle so far: https://codepen.io/skamansam/pen/NWvroeY?editors=1100

I can get all of the elements to resize accordingly (using max-width/height). when I use an image that is wider than taller, all works well. When I use an image that is taller than wider and exceeds the height of the box, the image overflows instead of respecting the max-width/height properties.

The most common answer involves wrapping the image in an html element and setting the width/height there, which I have done, but it doesn't solve the problem. Another common answer involves using combinations of `position` values, which didn't give any better results than I already have. Using the inspector, you can clearly see that all the elements EXCEPT the image are correctly sized, and the image overflows the container.

Is there any other way to get the `img` tag to respect `height: 100%` in the same way it respects `width: 100%`?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't illustrate the problem. It's just a blue square and a couple of arrows.

Comment: @BrettDonald I updated the fiddle to use codepen instead of jsfiddle. https://codepen.io/skamansam/pen/NWvroeY?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

you are using image with a very high resolution (500x800) , you have use little lower resolution otherwise you have to use overflow:hidden; on your wrapping div.Using max-width:100%; the image is already resizing itself but cannot resize further more, inspect the element to get a better understanding.

Comment: I have to use higher resolution images, as I don't know the size fo the images. Do you know of a way to resize these images dynaimcally, using css or javascript? My guess is that it would be more taxing (read: resource heavy) than necessary.

Comment: luckily, the answer is inside picksum itself, it allows you to choose the resolution of the image you want, you chose (500x800) that is way too large, you can use the following reduced resolutions >(50x80), (100x160), (180x288), (190x304), (200x320). I am sure you will get your desired result by using  (180x288) or (190x304)

Answer (score 0):

I made three changes:

- Your slide needs `width: auto;` and `height: 100%;`
- Your image needs `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;`
- Your image needs `object-fit: contain;` (not cover)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.jumbotron {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #aaa;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  height: 150px;
}

.jumbotron .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.my-carousel {
  background-color: #77f;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  // overflow: hidden;
}

.my-carousel .previous-btn, .my-carousel .next-btn {
    font-size: 200%;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.my-carousel .content {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    align-self: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.my-carousel .content .slide {
    height: 100%;
    //max-width: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    // width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: visible;
}
 
.my-carousel .content .slide.active {
    display: block;
}

.my-carousel .content .slide img {
    //position: relative;
    // margin: 0px auto;
    // box-sizing: border-box;
    // vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    // max-width: 100%;
    // max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    object-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
      
.my-carousel .content .slide .caption {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #fff, -2px -2px 4px #fff;
    stroke: 2px #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 150%;
    // color: #000;
    // -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    // -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.3.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main role="main">
  <section class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="my-carousel">
        <div class="previous-btn">
          <span class="mdi mdi-transfer-left"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="slide active">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/800?random=1" />
            <div class="caption">This is only a WIP to figure out how to style this carousel properly.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/400?random=1" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="next-btn">
          <span class="mdi mdi-transfer-right" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

luckily, the answer is inside "picksum"  itself, it allows you to choose the resolution of the image you want, you chose (500x800) that is way too large, you can use the following reduced resolutions >(50x80), (100x160), (180x288), (190x304), (200x320). I am sure you will get your desired result by using  (180x288) or (190x304)
for example:`<img src="https://picsum.photos/190/304?random=1" />`

Answer (score -1):

Use `max-width` and `max-height`

Like this

```css
.slide {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide .img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't work, as it violates the requirement of responsiveness. Setting the `slide` `width` and `height` to `100%` is already there and clearly does not work either.

Comment: Try to use `object-fit` property

Comment: I tried that as well, but it also did not work.